# PROLOG: “Syntax error: Operator expected”

Tags: prolog

I cannot figure out what's the problem in this code. Please help me out. I get this error:

```
ERROR: c:/users/ahmed/downloads/test.pl:2:4: Syntax error: Operator expected
% c:/Users/Ahmed/Downloads/test.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 21 clauses
```

Here is the code:

```
domains
disease,indication = symbol
Patient,name = string

predicates
hypothesis(string,disease)
symptom(name,indication)
response(char)
go

clauses
go :-
    write("What is the patient's name? "),
    readln(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.

go :-
    write("Sorry, I don't seem to be able to"),nl,
    write("diagnose the disease."),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a fever (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a rash (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a headache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a runny_nose (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a cough (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a body_ache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a chills (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sore_throat (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sneezing (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

response(Reply) :-
    readchar(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using SWI-Prolog, which follows Edinburgh syntax. The code looks like code for Visual Prolog, which follows different syntax rules. You need to port your code to the Edingburgh syntax if you want to run it under SWI-Prolog. Otherwise, you can install Visual Prolog and run the code there.

Comment: Agreed. I'd suggest deleting the first 11 lines from the top of the file (through "clauses") and see what results.

Comment: Tried deleting the first 11 lines. Got this error
    ERROR: c:/users/ahmed/downloads/test.pl:2:
        Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2
% c:/Users/Ahmed/Downloads/test.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 21 clauses

Comment: @AhmedFouda: it seems you don't know prolog really well. If you need to work on Visual Prolog sources, it will be better for you to download Visual Prolog—it's free for personal use. See http://www.visual-prolog.com/vip6/product/default.htm

Answer (score 1):

to be able to run that code in SWI-Prolog, you could *replace* starting lines (until `go :-` ...)  in this way:

```
:- redefine_system_predicate(write(_)).
:- redefine_system_predicate(readln(_)).

write(S) :-
    is_list(S) -> format('~s', [S]) ; format('~w', [S]).
write(A,B,C,D) :-
    maplist(write, [A,B,C,D]).
write(A,B,C) :-
    maplist(write, [A,B,C]).
readchar(S) :-
    get(C), atom_codes(S, [C]).
readln(A) :-
    system:readln(L), atomic_list_concat(L,' ',A).

go :-
   ...
```

after those 'adapter' predicates

```
?- go.
What is the patient's name? Carlo
Does Carlo have a fever (y/n) ?y
y
Does Carlo have a cough (y/n) ?|: y
y
Does Carlo have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?|: y
y
Does Carlo have a runny_nose (y/n) ?|: y
y
Does Carlo have a rash (y/n) ?|: y
y
Carloprobably has measles.
true .
```

Now it's time to know what is a *measles*. Going to Wikipedia... :)